# SqlConnection's executeAndWait causes memory leak on BB10

Tags: c++, sqlite, memory-leaks, blackberry-10, sqlconnection

When I call executeAndWait and just when the reply is returned I see a 76KB of memory increase in heap. I don't know why it happens. How do I clean this memory? My connection creation with db is following,

```
bool DBHelper::checkConnection(bool isAsynch)
{
    if(sqlConnector && dbFile->exists())
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (dbFile->exists())
    {
    sqlConnector = new SqlConnection(dbPath, "connect");
    connect(sqlConnector, SIGNAL(reply(const bb::data&colon;:DataAccessReply&)), this,
            SLOT(onLoadAsyncResultData(const bb::data&colon;:DataAccessReply&)));
    return true;
    }    
    return false;
}
```

The call to the executeAndWait is in this function,

```
void DBHelper::execute (const QVariant &criteria,int id,bool isAsynch)
{
    if (checkConnection(isAsynch))
    {
        if(!isAsynch)
        {
            DataAccessReply reply= sqlConnector->executeAndWait(criteria, id); // memory leak happens when the reply is found.
        this->onLoadSynchResultData(reply);
        }

    }
}
```

Documentation link is in [here.](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__data__sqlconnection.html)

Thanks.

Comment: I see that you allocating SqlConnection object every time overwriting previous pointer. You should clean it before you allocate new one. Better would be to use QSharedPointer rather than raw points

Comment: Not really. I create a SqlConection object if the object is already not created and the database file is also not created. So the object actually is created only once.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is a memory leak and not some inner mechanism of `DataAccessReply` class? Have you tried to ckeck it with valgrind or some similar tool?

From your allocation by using `new` and subsequent assignment I presume the type of `sqlConnector` is a pointer to something. Although it might not be the solution you are looking for I recommend using some smart pointer type as these are always more leak-proof.

If interested see e. g. [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) or C++11 [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) according to what is available to you.

Also (call me pedantic here) I would not use `if(sqlConnector)` even if it might be doing what you are expecting by implicit casting. I would explicitly use `if(sqlConnector != NULL)` (or something similar) and double check `sqlConnector` gets (also explicitly) initialized properly.